# Group SQL query side by side - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I've a complex query. So, I'll use a simple example which may illustrate my problem.

Imagine I have a query that show me the orders grouped by year.

```
Order No | Product | Price | Customer | Year
```

What I need to do is put this result side by side, by year.

```
00001 | T-Shirt | 15.00 | Smith | 2013 | 00002 | Jacket | 34.75 | Christine | 2012

(...)
```

Something like this:

[image]

What is the best (easier) way to get this kind of result?

Thanks ;)

Comment: it might be worth explaining why you need it side by side. will it be in sql that this is required? or front end application? and is there only going to be 2 orders side by side or _n_ number of orders side by side?

Comment: Why do you need such a query? Couldn't you just extract data "normally" and then use presentation layer for formatting. SQL is not really optimal for complex presentation. And if you need it to calculate upon in SQL, then chances are it can be made differently as well.

Comment: do you need just to concat rows 'side by side' ?

Comment: Don't ask me why. Ask my customer.

They use a spreedsheet in the format. This tool will export this result, in this format, to a excel file. But also was required show this kind of format on the app as well. =/

You know... customers... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You put things side-by-side in SQL by using JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the query below:

```
select STUFF(( 
        select  '|'
                ,[Order No]
                ,'|'
                ,Product
                ,'|'
                ,Price 
                ,'|'
                ,Customer 
                ,'|'
                ,Year
        from    myTable
        for xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')
```

Comment: No @Rubik. I had to edit the question in order provide a better explantion. Pls check the image above.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need half of the result on the left, and the other half on the right ? So each line of the CSV will contain 2 rows of the result of the query ?

Comment: Imagine that I run the query in SQL and its return me 100 lines grouped by year. 25 lines from 2009, 25 from 2010, 25 from 2011 and 25 from 2012. Now, I need to get this result and put this grouping side by side. Forget CSV, XLS or any other file. How can I do that in a sql result?

Comment: Let me clarify more. You need `(nb total of distinct years x 5) columns` in your final query result ? What if there are 20 lines for 2009 and 30 for 2010 and 25 for 2011 ? Columns should be left empty ?